# Why is sched breaking apart my strings

Tags: python, string, scheduler

I`m trying to use sched to run tweetsearch, function that takes one argument, a string.

```
s.enter(delaypercycle, 1, tweetsearch, "nike")
s.run()
```

This returns "TypeError: tweetsearch() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)".
Changing "nike" to "chicken" returns the same error, except with (7 given).

Any idea how to pass a string into sched?

Sample code that yields same error:

```
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def printword(word):
    print word
While True:
    s.enter(1, 1, printword, "chicken")
    s.run
```

Comment: Please add a minimal working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes a *tuple* of arguments. Passing in one string causes it to use that string as an iterable: each character becomes a separate argument.

Try passing a tuple instead: `("Nike",)` (note trailing comma).

Comment: Both answers solved my issue, but yours did a better job helping me understand why the string was being broken apart.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
s.enter(delaypercycle, 1, tweetsearch, ("nike",))
s.run()
```

`sched` was trying to do `tweetsearch(*"nike")`, which is equivalent to `tweetsearch('n', 'i', 'k', 'e')`.